# OpenSSL -nopad with ECB mode

Tags: cryptography, openssl

I was just trying to check if OpenSSL does use PCSK5 as documentation states when I got the following problem.

I first encrypted a plaintext and encrypted it using DES-ECB. I was expecting to see extra stuffed bytes in decrypted message but it seems OpenSSL is pretty smart and remove them before printing the result.

So I tried to use *-nopad* option, which

> disable standard block padding

following official documentation. This way extra bytes did not seem to be removed and result is choerent with PCSK5. My question is: does that prove anything? Disabling standard block padding (PCSK5) does not disable padding so what exactly it does? What type of padding does it use?

Here are my tests:

> Plaintext (What is the padding??????)
>
> 5B E0 A5 BD 8C CD F9 22 05 10 28 5C F8 6B 8D 22 6A 1F 06 A3 3E E7 C9 68 07 4E 92 AA >8D 07 EE AD
>
> Decrypted (nopad)
>
> 57 68 61 74 20 69 73 20 74 68 65 20 70 61 64 64 69 6E 67 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 0A 06 06 >06 06 06 06
>
> Decrypted (regular padding)
>
> 57 68 61 74 20 69 73 20 74 68 65 20 70 61 64 64 69 6E 67 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 0A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't see the padding in ciphertext because ciphertext is encrypted.

For commandline `openssl enc`, `-nopad` has effectively mirror meanings for encrypt and decrypt.

`-nopad` on encrypt means no padding is added (and the plaintext must be an exact multiple of the blocksize). You obviously did not specify `-nopad` on encrypt so PKCS5 padding was added by default (before encrypting).

On decrypt, by default PKCS5 padding is expected to be present and is removed; if the padding is not valid an error occurs. `-nopad` means no attempt is made to remove padding; if padding is present, as in your ciphertext, it is left in the data as you saw. If encrypt was done (successfully) with `-nopad` you need `-nopad` on decrypt so you don't try to remove padding that isn't there and fail.

PS- You are aware that single-DES has been broken and obsolete for years now, and ECB mode frequently allows system breaks unless used with great care?

[Lessons learned and misconceptions regarding encryption and cryptology](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology/2210)

[Block chaining modes to avoid](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27776/block-chaining-modes-to-avoid/)

[How are chosen plaintext attacks against ECB implemented in the real world?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62078/how-are-chosen-plaintext-attacks-against-ecb-implemented-in-the-real-world)

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12510/ecb-weakness-and-its-exploitation

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11451/can-ecb-mode-really-leak-some-characters

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanatio n! I wish OpenSSL was clear like that in it's documentation. Btw thanks for the observations over des and ecb security flaws. I am beggining to study crypto and those tips are very welcome :)